# Is there a way to get Django to reload after changes when using it with Docker?

Tags: django, docker, deployment, volumes

I'm relatively new to Docker/deployment in general.

I have a django app that utilizes rpy2 (not sure if relevant), that I have deployed using a docker container. However, I want to be able to continue developing the application and testing within the docker environment without having to spin the container up and down constantly.

I read that using volumes could help to bring this functionality back, but I either have gotten the container working and don't see updates, or I get errors saying that manae.py can't be found.

Is there any way to reintroduce the autoloading functionality?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.1.1
ENV RENV_VERSION 0.14.0


# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    python3-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libfontconfig1-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libharfbuzz-dev \
    libfribidi-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libtiff5-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libopenblas-dev \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    curl \
    libpq-dev

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cmake
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libxt6

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN R -e "install.packages('remotes')"
RUN R -e "remotes::install_github('rstudio/renv@${RENV_VERSION}')"
COPY renv.lock renv.lock
RUN R -e "renv::restore()"

RUN R_HOME=$(R RHOME) && echo "R_HOME=$R_HOME" && export R_HOME
ENV R_HOME=${R_HOME}


COPY custom_package.tar.gz custom_package.tar.gz
RUN R -e "remotes::install_local('custom_package.tar.gz', dependencies = F, force = T, upgrade = 'never')"

RUN R -e "install.packages('glmnet')"

## Expose port to allow app to run locally
EXPOSE 8000

COPY . .

CMD ["python3","manage.py","runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  django:
    image: django-docker:0.0.1
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
    - DEBUG=1
```

Comment: I frequently recommend doing day-to-day development work outside a container; in the case of Python, in a virtual environment.  The container will make sense for eventual integration testing and deployment.  If you have dependencies like databases, you can point host code at a container database.  Would a setup like that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just map the volume of your app directory and your development server will auto reload depending on your file changes just as if you were developing in a standard python virtual environment.

```
 version: '3.8'

  services:
  django:
    image: django-docker:0.0.1
    build:
      context: './app'
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
    - DEBUG=1
    volumes:
    - "./app:/app"
```

Just some slight changes to your docker compose config. In this configuration, the `docker-compose.yaml` is in the root directory of the project. The entire `Django project` and its `Dockerfile` is in folder called `app` within the project root directory.

The key is mapping the volumes "./app:/app".

Comment: Hmm I tried the way you suggested but am still having issues.

I've restructured the project so that docker-compose.yml is in the root, and then I have a folder called 'django-app' containing the django project and manage.py

I've left the content of the Dockerfile unchanged (as above), and then updated docker-compose as below. But I still get an error saying python3: can't open file 'manage.py'


version: '3.8'

services:
  django:
    image: django-docker:0.0.1
    build:
      context: './django-app'
    environment:
    - DEBUG=1
    volumes:
    - "./django-app:/app"

Comment: Seems like you got some issues with your docker image. Did it build fine??